# How to identify actions instantiated from same activation bar is not happened concurrently? (Sequence digram)

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

[image: UML]

I am looking on a sequence diagram similar to the attached snapshot, object A instantiated 3 actions on same activation bar and received by object B with same activation bar as well.

So can I say the 3 functions are being executed one after one? Since they are solid arrowhead, I not sure my understanding is correct.

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Your diagram is incorrect, an _ExecutionSpecification_ represents the execution of   one and only action/behavior, but the _ExecutionSpecification_ on the lifeline of the _Object B_ represents three

Comment: @bruno yea, that's the reason this question came from, i capture this from a SRS and it confused me

Comment: Finally I put an answer because the other answer is partial and focused on the messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I say the 3 functions are being executed one after one? Since they are solid arrowhead

The arrows indicate synchronous messages, so the second message cannot be send before the end of the execution of *function A*, the first cannot be sent before the end of the execution of *function B* and *ExecutionSpecification* on the lifeline of *Object A* cannot end before the end of the execution of *function C*.

> object A instantiated 3 actions on same activation bar

All these three messages can start from the same *ExecutionSpecification* on the lifeline of *Object A*

> 3 actions ... received by object B with same activation bar

This is invalid, an *ExecutionSpecification* represents the execution of one and only action/behavior, so you need three *ExecutionSpecification* on the lifeline of the *Object B*, you cannot have only one.

A valid diagram can be :

[image]

or also showing the returns :

[image]

(on them `function_c` is not immediately called when `function_b` returns, the execution on *object a* does 'something' before introducing a delay, and also 'something' after)

---

from your remark :

> From the requirements saying these 3 functions should be executed by objectB concurrently. That means i should use line arrow head instead of solid arrow head? And can i use the same ExecutionSpecification on objectB if functions are executed concurrently?

If you use asynch calls (open arrow head) there is no return message, so *object a* cannot know when the execution ends and it can sent immediately the next message.

The fact the 3 functions should be executed by *object b* concurrently is something else, asynch calls can be executed in sequence by the receiver, and the fact the receiver does concurrent executions does not *imply* asynch calls, but yes you *can* use asynch calls.

You still have to use 3 *ExecutionSpecification* on *object b*, to show concurrent execution just use a *combined fragment "par"*.

So for instance :

[image]

Comment: From the requirements saying these 3 functions should be executed by `objectB` concurrently. That means i should use line arrow head instead of solid arrow head? And can i use the same ExecutionSpecification on `objectB` if functions are executed concurrently?
BTW, I appreciates the clear explanation above.

Comment: You claim that B must have three separate activation bars, with the argument that an ExecutionSpecification represents the execution of one and only one action/behavior, right? In this case you are right, unless B, upon executing function A, starts a new thread that is active until the execution of function C stops.